# how to use autofill in discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

There is YAGPBD bot which has a function i want to use.
For example if i type /giverole its autofill the input field with name: and role:
How could i make my commands use this function?
i cannot even find the function name in documentary..
its looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCGZW.jpg

i want the same function as yagpbd bot
i tried use the easy way but its not 'userfriendly'
heres my code:
`@give_role.command(name='giverole') async def giverole(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role): await member.add_roles(role) await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} hozzáadva a {role.mention} role-hoz"`

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible for slash commands, hence the `/` prefix that opens up a GUI, and you don't have to do anything special to make the parameters display. Discord does it automatically.

It's not possible to do this for message commands. Read the docs or examples on slash commands for info on how to get started: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.pyz